# yii2 detailview set value with function htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

How to set value for `DetailView`. I am trying by set value `gridview` way but that just show error result

This is the code i wrote

```
<?php echo  DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'username',
        'email',
        [   'label' => 'Nama',
            'value' => function($model) { return $model->first_name ." ". $model->last_name; },
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

The error is :

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `DetailView` no need to use `function` in `value` property.

```
  <?php echo  DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'username',
        'email',
        [   'label' => 'Name',
            'value' => $model->first_name ." ". $model->last_name,
        ],
    ],
  ]); ?>
```

Comment: Yii2 docs really needs to state DetailView does not accept anonymous fn()'s whereas Grid and List do.